# how do i Sleep C++ for 3 seconds then it start

Tags: c++

Hello i am learning C++ and i want to know how to pause my code for 3 seconds before it begins
so when the person hits enter it will pause for three seconds

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int x = 10;
cout<<"BEGIN\n";
cin.get();
while( x < 11 ) {
   cout<<"123456789";
}
}
```

Comment: #include <windows.h> Sleep(500) to sleep 500 milliseconds

Comment: @cageman, Who said anything about Windows? There's a standard sleep function: `std::this_thread::sleep_for` or `std::this_thread::sleep_until`.

Comment: Thats why i didn't put it as an answer, but a quick comment.

Comment: @chris: Only in C++11 and beyond.  No thread support for earlier versions.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, Yes, unfortunately. Boost still has them, though.

Answer (score 0):

Delays and timing are a platform issue and you need to use platform specific API for this.

Search the web for your Platform API and the words "sleep event".